# Java 8 streams adding values from two or more lists in single Map

Tags: java-8, hashmap, java-stream

I am having an arraylist like below:

```
stackedBarChart.stackedBarChartSeries.data.add(1,2,3)
stackedBarChart.stackedBarChartSeries.data.add(3,4,5)
stackedBarChart.stackedBarChartSeries.data.add(4,5,6)
stackedBarChart.stackedBarChartSeries.data.add(6,7,8)
```

And Another list

```
stackedBarChart.XAxis.add("Jan","Feb","March")
```

And I wants to make Map<String, Integer> where map will be like:

Jan = 14, Feb = 18, March = 22

Where each value represent the addition of each index of arraylist from stackedBarChart.

For now I have done this using simple for loop like below:

```
stackedBarChart.stackedBarChartSeries.forEach(stackedBarChartTableDataList ->{
    for(int i = 0; i < stackedBarChart.getXAxis().size();i++) {
             Integer stackedBarChartTableData = stackedBarChartTableDataList.getData().get(i);
             String stackedBarChartTableCurrentColumnName =  stackedBarChart.getXAxis().get(i);
             stackedBarChartTableColumnSumMap.merge(stackedBarChartTableCurrentColumnName, stackedBarChartTableData, Integer::sum);
        }
})
```

I wants to have a simple solution to achieve this using stream, or any other simple way than using for loop.

Can you please help me for this?

Edit:

Here is object representation:

```
{
"stackedBarChart": {
    "stackedBarChartSeries": [
        {
            "data": [
                1,
                2,
                3
            ]
        },
        {
            "data": [
                3,
                4,
                5
            ]
        },
        {
            "data": [
                4,
                5,
                6
            ]
        },
        {
            "data": [
                6,
                7,
                8
            ]
        }
    ]
},
"xAxis": [
    "Jan 2021",
    "Feb 2021",
    "Mar 2021"
]
```

}

Comment: Provide more detail about your objects structures.

Comment: Hi @HadiJ ,

{
 "stackedBarChart": {
  "stackedBarChartSeries": [
   {
    "data": [
     1,
     2,
     3
    ]
   },
   {
    "data": [
     3,
     4,
     5
    ]
   },
   {
    "data": [
     4,
     5,
     6
    ]
   },
   {
    "data": [
     6,
     7,
     8
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 "xAxis": [
  "Jan 2021",
  "Feb 2021",
  "Mar 2021"
 ]
}

Comment: `stackedBarChart.stackedBarChartSeries.forEach(sbcs ->
                IntStream.range(0, stackedBarChart.getxAxis().size())
                        .forEach(i -> stackedBarChartTableColumnSumMap.merge(stackedBarChart.getxAxis().get(i), sbcs.getData().get(i), Integer::sum)));` your version is more readable.

Comment: Thanks you so much @HadiJ, this is the answer I was looking for. Appreciate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From https://stackoverflow.com/users/3669698/hadi-j,

```
stackedBarChart.stackedBarChartSeries.forEach(sbcs ->
IntStream.range(0, stackedBarChart.getxAxis().size())                         
.forEach(i ->  stackedBarChartTableColumnSumMap.merge(stackedBarChart.getxAxis().get(i), sbcs.getData().get(i), 
Integer::sum)));
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```java
public static Map<String, Integer> mergeBySum(Map<String, Integer> map1, Map<String, Integer> map2) {
    return Stream.of(map1, map2)
            .map(Map::entrySet)
            .flatMap(Set::stream)
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Entry::getKey, Entry::getValue, (u1, u2) -> u1 + u2));
}

public Map<String, Integer> sumByMonth(/*bar chart type*/ stackedBarChart) {
    List<String> xAxis = stackedBarChart.getXAxis();
    int axisLength = xAxis.size();
    return stackedBarChart.stream().map(stackedBarChartTableDataList ->
        IntStream.range(0, axisLength).boxed().collect(Collectors.toMap(xAxis::get, stackedBarChartTableDataList::get))
    ).reduce((map1, map2) -> mergeBySum(map1, map2)).orElse(Collections.EMPTY_MAP);
}
```